# After I installed wicd my wireless network interface disappeared. How do I fix it?

Tags: 11.04, wireless

I had some issues with my wireless at my school. I had tried everything almost and usually it did not want to connect, or when it connected, it disconnected again a few minutes later.

Someone suggested that I could install Windows Wireless drivers. I did that and had better luck connecting, but still disconnection issues.

Then someone suggested wicd. I install that and after I did that, wlan0 disappeared. I could not connect in any way with wicd and even after uninstalling it and installing network-manager again, it is still not there. (and countless reboots).

I have tried adding

```
auto wlan0 inet dhcp
```

To interfaces but nothing works. The wired connection still works fine.

Comment: can you confirm how you installed network-manager - did you `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome` ?

Comment: I installed it via apt-get install network-manager (not gnome)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just reinstalled ubuntu and it works now. I had gone through all the ubuntu wireless troubleshooting guides out there. Nothing worked.